# ROS Service to Show Image

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04` and `ROS Noetic`, `OpenCV version 4.2.0.34` I'm creating a ros service to show an image:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
import cv2
from img_reader.srv import ImgReader, ImgReaderResponse

def showImage(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow('img')

def readImgCB(req):
    try:
        showImage(req.img_path)
        msg = ""
        return ImgReaderResponse(True, msg)
    except:
        msg = "Image Path is Incorrect"
        return ImgReaderResponse(False, msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rospy.init_node("img_reader")
        rospy.Service("img_reader_srv", ImgReader, readImgCB)
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.logerr("Error")
```

#### ImgReader.srv

```
# Desired image path.
string img_path

---

uint16 result_code

# Status message (empty if service succeeded).
string message
```

The service works well in the first time, but I can't call it in the next time due to `cv2.namedWindow()` can't create a new window even though I destroyed the last one!

Can you please tell me how can I fix that please? thanks in advance.

Comment: first, remove the "except:" and look at the exceptions you're getting

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz "*the exceptions you're getting*" I'm not getting any exception or error (after removing the exception handeling), the program execution stuck at the point of `cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` with no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be multiple problems but I could narrow down to a single one so I detail how I solved it.

#### Full code that works on my machine (.msg file remains the same):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
import cv2
from test.srv import ImgReader, ImgReaderResponse

def showImage(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    try:
        cv2.destroyWindow('img')
    except cv2.error:
        print("Window already closed. Ignoring")

def readImgCB(req):
    try:
        showImage(req.img_path)
        msg = ""
        return ImgReaderResponse(True, msg)
    except cv2.error:
        msg = "Image Path is Incorrect"
        return ImgReaderResponse(False, msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rospy.init_node("img_reader")
        rospy.Service("img_reader_srv", ImgReader, readImgCB)
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.logerr("Error")
```

#### What I changed:

Changed `DetectEdgesResponse` to `ImgReaderResponse` because it should match service you call

```
from test.srv import ImgReader, ImgReaderResponse
```

```
    return ImgReaderResponse(True, msg)
except:
    msg = "Image Path is Incorrect"
    return ImgReaderResponse(False, msg)
```

Added `cv2.error` exception to make it less broad:

```
except cv2.error:
        msg = "Image Path is Incorrect"
        return ImgReaderResponse(False, msg)
```

Catch exception (it fixes wrong ImgReaderResponse):

```
    try:
        cv2.destroyWindow('img')
    except cv2.error:
        print("Window already closed. Ignoring")
```

I'll give some general advice (which actually helped me find this bug while writing this answer):

1. Don't use [bare `except`](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/articles/s/python-bare-except). It's bad practice unless it's really needed. **It will catch ALL exceptions even ones you don't even know exists** (now after the fact I can double down on this statement) therefore when program crashes you won't know why because error won't be printed.

   I like method of intentionally crashing code and copy pasting exception to `except CopiedException`. This way it only catches exceptions you know about.

In your case it would look like:

```
def readImgCB(req):
    showImage("intentionally_crash_it_with_a_wrong_path")
```

Error:

```
File ".../src/img_opener.py", line 11, in showImage\n    cv2.imshow(\'img\', img)\n', "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'\n\n"] [ERROR][/img_reader]
```

Notice `cv2.error`

Corrected function with `except cv2.error`:

```
def readImgCB(req):
    try:
        showImage(req.img_path)
        msg = ""
        return ImgReaderResponse(True, msg)
    except cv2.error:
        msg = "Image Path is Incorrect"
        return ImgReaderResponse(False, msg)
```

And even `except cv2.error` is too broad exception because you can't differentiate what cause it. But it's limited by OpenCV so **probably** there's nothing you can do about it.

After more debugging and removing too broad `except cv2.error` I found the problem. It also caught and suppressed exception of `cv2.destroyWindow('img')`. It's thrown because if you press X to close window it happens at `cv2.waitKey(0)` and windows gets closed before executing `cv2.destroyWindow('img')` and because there's no window to close it throws exception.

Comment: thanks for the `ImgReaderResponse` note, indeed that was a typo while copying the MWE, I press `q` to close the first window, and the whole code is executed well in the first time without issues!, the issue in creating a new window in the second time.

Comment: I have corrected the `ImgReaderResponse` typo in the question, thanks again for your remark.

Comment: @Bilal Did it fix your problem? It worked fine on my machine so if it didn't it might be not related to code

Comment: It might be related to the OpenCV version or the machine itself, I will retest with another machine and tell you the result, thanks.

Comment: I have recompiled OpenCV `4.7` from source and it works properly, the problem is caused by an older version of `OpenCV`